# Load <select> options via a MySQL table, and allow the user to add to it via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a MySQL table which looks like this:

```
ID   OPTION
1    First
2    Second
```

The user sees the following:

```
<div id="options">
 <select>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

I would like the user to have the option to insert into the table, as follows:

```
<div id="add">
 <input type="text" name="newOption" placeholder="Your own option">
 <input type="button" value="Add">
</div>
```

It would then select their newly-added option:

```
<div id="options">
 <select>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Third</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

As the above code is part of a page which contains other form elements the page can't be reloaded, otherwise the data they've already typed will disappear. So I'd like to use jQuery.

EDIT: I have tried the following but it adds rows twice, sometimes even four times, for reasons I cannot fathom!

```
$("#button").click(function(){
 var test = $("#<?php echo $selectName; ?>").val();
 var dataString = 'select=<?php echo $select; ?>&selectName='+ test;

 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "optionAdd.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
 $("#<?php echo $select; ?>List").load("optionList.php?select=<?php echo $select; if ($_GET[required] == "no") { echo "&required=no"; } ?>");
     }
  });
});
```

The reason for the PHP above is I want to use multiples of this code on the same form and so I'm using GET to select the options, as it were.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) - Have a look at something like [jQuery's Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) have a go at it and if you get stuck, post some code you are having issues with and need help with. Asking general questions i.e: `What is the best approach` are to broad and are not a good fit to the [expected Q&A format](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) on SO

Comment: I tried loading the list from another PHP file and when the user clicks 'Add' it submits to another PHP file, then reloads the list. But it intermittently adds multiples for some reason. So this method isn't right.

Comment: why didn't you post the code you tried in the first place??  All you need is `load()` from your code which is itself an ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to send an AJAX request to server with the new data and get an ID returned for this new option. Once the ID is received you can create the `option` with the new ID as value and the user defined text

```
$('#add button').click(function(){
     /* get value from previous input*/
    var newOpt=$(this).prev().val();
     /* make AJAX "POST" request*/
    $.post( 'path/to/server/file', { newOption: newOpt}, function( newId ){
         /* ajax successfully completed, add new option*/
         $('#options select').append('<option value="'+ newId +'">'+newOpt+'</option>');
    });
    return false; /* prevent browser default handling of button click*/
})
```

At server receive the data as you would a form field with `name="newOption"` ie `$_POST['newOption']` and send back a new ID as text

Alternatively you could send back all the options as html in sort order you want and replace all the options in the select.

```
    /* ajax to replace all options with html from server*/
    $.post( 'path/to/server/file', { newOption: newOpt}, function( response ){
         /* ajax successfully completed, add new option*/
         $('#options select').html( response);
    });
```

Comment: I see! So rather than reload the list externally, just add to it via jQuery. Is there a way I can reload the list though? It's listed alphabetically at present and your method would add to the bottom I believe.

Comment: I just adde additional coment that if easier due to sort order send back all the option html. Can sort also with jQUery but to keep this simple am avoiding that

Comment: Trying your alternative now. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: my alternative is really the same as you using `load()`. You had too many ajax operations, `load()` was sufficient by itself

Comment: Your method is better than mine in that I can keep the <select> options and just load the <option> part. Thank you for your help and apologies to all for my messy approach to this thread!

Comment: great.. BTW , always post code. WOuld have had better response identifying where you were going wrong rather than just getting some new copy/paste code. Got impression you didn't know about AAJX the way question phrased

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery AJAX to call a PHP Script to store the new option to the database, that returns the new ID and the given option name on success and then add the new entry to the `<select>` using Javascript.